# Couldn't install Microsoft.Net.4.6.FullRedist.NonThreshold

Tags: visual-studio

Couldn't install Microsoft.Net.4.6.FullRedist.NonThreshold

I'm getting this error while trying to install Visual Studio, any advise how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: can you see that [developercommunity.visualstudio.com](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/124195/package-microsoftnet46fullredistnonthresholdversio.html)

Comment: Nothing worked, it's pretty frustrating!

Comment: were you able to solve it?